# SQL Count then Sum?

Tags: sql, count, sum

```
Select Bill.BillId, Count(Menu.MenuId) * Sum(ShoppingCart.Number) As 'Sum'
From ShoppingCart
Left Join Bill On Bill.BillId = ShoppingCart.Bill
Right Join Menu On Menu.MenuId = ShoppingCart.Menu
Group By Bill.BillId, Menu.MenuId, ShoppingCart.Number
```

Result:

```
Billid:    Sum:
1          1
1          1
2          2
2          1
3          3
3          5
```

Hey guys,
I'm trying to count how many dishes have been ordered but the problem is 
that the different dishes dont Sum together.

For explanation:
In BillId you can order different dishes,
in MenuId you can find the dish an
in number you can find the number of orders of a dish.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? What is your sample input and output?

Comment: Omit MenuId from your GROUP BY clause

Comment: Nothing in your data is called "dish", so I'm confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select sc.BillId, m.DishId, count(*) as dishes
from ShoppingCart sc join
     Menu m
     on m.MenuId = sc.Menu
group by sc.BillId, m.DishId;
```

You should not need outer joins if your data model is set up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Only use the columns which are not aggregated in group by statement, so the group by statement should contain only BillID. If you include MenuId and ShoppingCart.Number then the individual values in those columns will also get group by instead of getting the aggregated value.

```
Select Bill.BillId, Count(Menu.MenuId) * Sum(ShoppingCart.Number) As 'Sum'
From ShoppingCart
Left Join Bill On Bill.BillId = ShoppingCart.Bill
Right Join Menu On Menu.MenuId = ShoppingCart.Menu
Group By Bill.BillId
```